# To check the Injectivity of Function $f(x)=x^2\sin{x}$

Tags: functions

If $f(x)=x^2\sin{x}, \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$,prove that $f(x)$ is not injective by the method of considering $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ by finding a relationship between $x_1$ and $x_2$ other than $x_1=x_2$.

Comment: Can you find $x_1,x_2$  such that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=0$?

Comment: yes, but can we find another relation between $x_1$ and $x_2$ other than $x_1=x_2$

Comment: @FriedSpies At what real values do $\sin x$ vanish?

Comment: like $x_1=\pi/2$ and $x_2=5\pi/2$

Comment: Not quite. $\sin(\pi/2)=\sin(5\pi/2)=1$.

Comment: these 2 values would make $sinx$ =1 and hence lhs and rhs won't be equal

Comment: Look at my answer. We have to have $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$, but then $x_1\neq x_2$. Your examples would make it so that $f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)$ so they wouldn't work.

Comment: Oh now i understand, i must make sin x =0

Comment: Yes because if $\sin x=0,$ then certainly $x^2 \sin x=0.$ So what are some $x$ values such that $\sin x=0$? How are they related?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the condition of injectivity says something along these lines: Suppose $f:A\to B$. We say that $f$ is injective, or one-to-one, if for all $x_1,x_2\in A, f(x_1)=f(x_2)\implies x_1=x_2$. The negation of this statement is there exists $x_1,x_2\in A$ such that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ and $x_1\neq x_2.$ So find such an $x_1$ and $x_2$. When is $\sin\theta=0$?

Comment: If we have to give relationship between $x_1$ and $ x_2 $ other than $x_1=x_2 $

Comment: What do you mean? $x_1\neq x_2$ is certainly a different relationship from $x_1=x_2.$

Comment: Yes but there should be some other algebraic expression relating them

Comment: Ok sorry this is unclear, let me explain a little more intuitively maybe. So basically for a function to be injective, or one-to-one, every number you put into the function has to spit out a unique answer that no other number you put into the function will give.

Comment: So then we have the condition $f(x_1)=f(x_2)\implies x_1=x_2$. What that says is that in order for injectivity to hold, if two numbers create the same output from your function, then they must be the same.

Comment: No its clear that by taking counter example we prove that its not one-one, but what i am actually looking is the other relation between $x_1$ and $x_2$ that connects them rather just than the expression $x_1 \not= x_2$

Comment: For your example, that is not true. We can think of two numbers where if we put them in the function, the output of the function will be the same, BUT the numbers themselves aren't the same.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well you could have that $x_1<x_2$ or $x_1>x_2.$ Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I am looking for a relation in which if we consider either to be any value we get the other one which is not equal to it